# Removing Google Maps Markers that are added dynamically with hover event over Chart.js Chart

Tags: javascript, google-maps, chart.js

I have a google map and a Chart.js chart. When you hover over a certain part of the chart a corresponding marker on the map is created. However I would like to remove the previous marker every time a new marker is place don the map but cannot seem to do so. I have tried pushing the markers to an array but when I try to log the array it only has an individual marker even if there are several on the map due to hovering. Here is the code I have in my map.js file (this comes after the mapinit function):

> `function findLatLng(data, index) {
>
> var getDataFiltered = formatData(data)
>
> var markerPosition = {
>       lat: getDataFiltered[index].values.positionLat,
>       lng: getDataFiltered[index].values.positionLong   }
>
> var markers = []
>
> var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: markerPosition, map:
>   map, title: 'stamp'});   markers.push(marker)
>
> addMarker(markerPosition) }
>
> function addMarker(position) {
>
> var markers = []
>
> var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: marker, map: map,
>   title: 'stamp'});   markers.push(marker)
>
> if (marker.visible) {
>       marker.visible === false   }
>
> if (markers.length >= 2) {
>       markers[0].setMap(null);   }
>
> function clearMarkers(markers) {
>       if (markers.length > 1) {
>         markers[0].setMap(null);
>       }   } }`

I call the findLatLang function from the graph.js file here with the hover event option.

```
`  hover: {
      onHover: function(element) {
        if (element.length > 0) {
          findLatLng(data, element[0]._index)
        }
     }
  },`
```